# Error in SQL logic

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this SQL query:

```
SELECT r.room_id AS room_id, 
       room_name, 
       num_rooms, 
       max_people, 
       min_rate 
FROM   room r 
       LEFT JOIN(SELECT b.room_id, 
                        accom_id, 
                        COALESCE(Count(b . room_id), 0) AS bookings 
                 FROM   booking b 
                 WHERE  arr_date >= :ind 
                        AND dep_date <= :outd 
                 GROUP  BY room_id) t 
              ON( t.accom_id = r.accom_id 
                  AND r.room_id = t.room_id ) 
WHERE  r.accom_id = :id 
       AND ( t.bookings < num_rooms 
              OR t.bookings IS NULL ) 
GROUP  BY room_name
```

Which relates to the following SQL Table:

[image]

It has this information in booking table for testing purposes:
[image]

The problem is:

When I run the query where :ind is 2014-07-27 and :outd is 2014-07-29 I get a return of nothing, which is  exactly what I expect! However, if I change the dates to 2014-07-28(:ind) and 2014-07-29(:outd)

Both rooms are returned to me! Which is incorrect. Room_id 2 should return to me, because the previous guest would have departed on the 28th, so 28-29 is free, but room_id 1 shouldn't be available because guest is still staying in it until 29th.

How can I fix this logical error? Where is my SQL going wrong?

edit: "what does the sql actually do?" It is meant to check when there are bookings in rooms, and if the rooms have no bookings in them on the given dates, then they are free to be booked into, so it should return free rooms. Basically.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: What types are your columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Garett is ever so right. 
But also: Your query is more complicated than it needs to be.

```
SELECT r.room_id AS room_id, 
       room_name, 
       num_rooms 
FROM   room r 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   booking b 
        WHERE  b.room_id = r.room_id 
               AND b.accom_id = r.accom_id 
               AND ( arr_date BETWEEN @ind AND @outd 
                      OR dep_date BETWEEN @ind AND @outd )) < num_rooms
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d67fb5/1

Answer (score 2):

It's going wrong in the where clause which has the :ind and :outd parameter.

You should have
WHERE (arr_date <= :outd AND dep_date >= :ind) OR (dep_date >= :ind AND arr_date <= :outd)

Currently, the query is only excluding rooms which are already booked within the requested period, rather than rooms which have bookings that overlap with the requested period.